# Facebook admob mediation SDK Causing CRASH

Tags: android, ads, facebook-audience-network, native-ads, mobile-ad-mediation

I recently update my app's facebook admob mediation sdk to the latest one and getting a crash because of ClassCastException the below is the stack trace i get. I am using this version of sdk.

**implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.2.0.1'**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewRootImpl cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
   at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Th.A0I(Th.java:55202)
   at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.5C.registerViewForInteraction(5C.java:13152)
   at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.5C.registerViewForInteraction(5C.java:13147)
   at com.facebook.ads.NativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(NativeAd.java:213)
   at com.google.ads.mediation.facebook.FacebookAdapter$UnifiedAdMapper.trackViews(FacebookAdapter.java:939)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaoo.zzc(zzaoo.java:62)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzanl.zza(zzanl.java:88)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzgv.onTransact(zzgv.java:13)
   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:949)
   at fx.aW(fx.java:2)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mediation.client.r.x(r.java)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.nativead.ck.a(ck.java:25)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.nativead.aj.h(aj.java:4)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.nativead.ag.run(ag.java)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at qd.a(qd.java)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.f.a(f.java:1)
   at qd.dispatchMessage(qd.java)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Comment: You should be posting this crash info. on Audience Network Developer support forums.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and it was solved by registering the ad view after the fragment started.

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed this was an NPE bug in play-services and [reported](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/r1M1rlDXT6k/m/n8M2M4GjAAAJ) this to Admob on Jan 27th. It should be resolved already since Feb 16th.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is also mentioned in this [googleads-mobile-unity](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/1591) issue on google mobile ads github repo.

The problem is that facebook mediation is depended on google mobile ads version 20 and since this version is not yet associated to admob mediation package (android, iOS or unity) it is causing you crash.

Also this issue have not been yet resolved by admob support.